# Составить regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строки `data("информация")`
Есть выражение `data((.*)*)`, которое находит строку целиком. Как найти в строках начинающихся с `data(`, вот эти символы - `")`

В файле есть и другие данные, кроме этих.
Например:

```
func("")
'text")'
```

Только используя регулярные выражения ( если такое вообще возможно )
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: например, `/"\)/`

Comment: data\(.*?(\"\))

Comment: @splash58 находит в любых строках

@Алексей находит data(" , а не последнюю кавычку и закрывающую скобку - `")`

Comment: что значит `как найти в строках начинающихся с data(, вот эти символы - ")` - вы хотите их на что-то поменять?

Comment: Да, `data("text")` хочу поменять на `data(text\n")`.
То есть, `")` на `\n")`

Comment: какой язык? там есть разница

Comment: Движок модуля RE в python или boost в c++

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/r7wNIO/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно искать две группы `data(...` и `")` и между ними вставить перевод строки

```
(data\([^)]*?)(\"\))
```

заменить на

```
\1\n\2
```

**[demo](https://regex101.com/r/r7wNIO/1)**